# Why a core was generated when I run the code "foreach" with PHP compiled with "--enable-debug"

Tags: php

I read data from xml files with protobuf, and then When I run the code "foreach data", a core was generated by `php-fpm: pool www`,

PHP was compiled with "--enable-debug",

here is the gdb errors:

```
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7ffff7ffa000
Core was generated by `php-fpm: pool www            '.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000000000079407b in ZEND_FE_RESET_SPEC_CV_HANDLER (execute_data=0x7ffff7fb5118) at /home/wyq/php-5.6.14/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:31510
31510   /home/wyq/php-5.6.14/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h: No such file or directory.
    in /home/wyq/php-5.6.14/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000000000079407b in ZEND_FE_RESET_SPEC_CV_HANDLER (execute_data=0x7ffff7fb5118) at /home/wyq/php-5.6.14/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:31510
#1  0x000000000074067a in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7ffff7fb5118) at /home/wyq/php-5.6.14/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#2  0x00000000007406fc in zend_execute (op_array=0xf69868) at /home/wyq/php-5.6.14/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:388
#3  0x00000000006e5138 in zend_call_function (fci=0x7fffffff8bb0, fci_cache=0x7fffffff8b80) at /home/wyq/php-5.6.14/Zend/zend_execute_API.c:829
#4  0x00000000005ce6b7 in zif_call_user_func_array (ht=2, return_value=0x14d35c8, return_value_ptr=0x7ffff7fb4180, this_ptr=0x0, return_value_used=0)
    at /home/wyq/php-5.6.14/ext/standard/basic_functions.c:4784
#5  0x0000000000741013 in zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC (execute_data=0x7ffff7fb4198) at /home/wyq/php-5.6.14/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:558
#6  0x0000000000746a11 in ZEND_DO_FCALL_SPEC_CONST_HANDLER (execute_data=0x7ffff7fb4198) at /home/wyq/php-5.6.14/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:2602
#7  0x000000000074067a in execute_ex (execute_data=0x7ffff7fb4198) at /home/wyq/php-5.6.14/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:363
#8  0x00000000007406fc in zend_execute (op_array=0x7ffff7fe7d50) at /home/wyq/php-5.6.14/Zend/zend_vm_execute.h:388
#9  0x00000000006fadf5 in zend_execute_scripts (type=8, retval=0x0, file_count=3) at /home/wyq/php-5.6.14/Zend/zend.c:1341
#10 0x0000000000660b72 in php_execute_script (primary_file=0x7fffffffd380) at /home/wyq/php-5.6.14/main/main.c:2597
#11 0x00000000007be875 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffd5a8) at /home/wyq/php-5.6.14/sapi/fpm/fpm/fpm_main.c:1964
```

Comment: Please show us the code that produces the segfault

Comment: Sorry, it's my company's code, but it looks like this: $data = $this->_read(); foreach ($data as $key => $val) { ///... }  , thank you !